# MySQL NDB Cluster Buffer Overflow Error

Tags: docker, docker-compose, mysql-cluster

I have a mysql cluster setup in docker using the official mysql-cluster image in dockerhub.I also have other conatiners like which has Redis and a node application running in same network as that of the mysql cluster.

When I try to run `docker-compose up` it shows : `Buffer Overflow Error`

I have tried increasing the buffer memory and and cache memory for mysql-server, but still cannot undertand why I am getting this error.Otherwise everything seems to be working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the same, but this looks similar:
https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/issues/243